# Counting rules - ordered and unordered sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

A bag contains n differently coloured balls, If three balls are successively drawn at random, with replacement, what is the probability that at least two balls of the same colour are drawn?

This is a question in my note and the answer is provided. My question is:

the answer said the sample is ORDERED and I dont understand why.

My thought is that if I draw three balls, for example:

red, red, blue

blue, red, red

red, blue, red

They are all the same, because I just need to know what colour and how many of each colour were drawn. In this case, 2 red and 1 blue, and the order does not matter.

Anyone knows why this should be an ordered sample instead of unordered?

Comment: Or anyone agrees with me that the sample should be unordered ?

Comment: If unordered, consider that their probabilities won't all be the same. Eg among two coin tosses, is two heads equally probable as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat similar problem (with specific numbers of balls) that illustrates how certain kinds of combinatorial problems might be worked in several ways.

> Suppose the bag contains 3 red and 2 green balls, and two balls
>   are withdrawn at random without replacement. What is the probability
>   that they are of the same color?

Method 1 (General multiplication rule):
$P(R_1R_2) = P(R_1)P(R_2 | R_1) = (3/5)(2/4) = 6/20.$
Similarly, $P(G_1G_2) = 2/20.$ So $P(\text{Same Color})  = 6/20 + 2/20  = 2/5.$

Method 2 (Unordered): $P(\text{Both R}) = {3 \choose 2}/{5 \choose 2} = 3/10.$
Similarly, $P(\text{Both G}) = 1/10,$ so $P(\text{Same Color}) = 3/10 + 1/10 = 2/5.$

Method 3 (Ordered): $P(\text{Both R}) = P(3,2)/P(5,2) = 6/20.$
Similarly, $P(\text{Both G}) = 2/20,$ so 
$P(\text{Same Color}) = 6/20 + 2/20 = 2/5.$

If we choose Method 2, we have a sample space of 10 equally likely unordered outcomes in the denominator and the numerator must also deal with
unordered outcomes. Perhaps red balls are lettered A, B, C and green
balls D and E.  Then the sample space is $$\{AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE, CD, CE, DE\},$$ of which AB, AC, BC, and DF are 'favorable'. Notice that in this
unordered sample space AB and BA would be the same outcome; we put letters in
alphabetical order because the real order doesn't matter.

If we chose Method 3, we have twice as many (ordered) outcomes in the sample space
and twice as many 'favorable' ones, so the answer is the same with both methods.

Notice that we have our choice of methods because the event of interest
does not depend on the order of selection. If the question had been "What
is the probability that the second ball drawn is Red?" then Method 2 cannot
be used.

*Note:* This problem can also be solved using the hypergeometric distribution,
where $X$ is the number of red balls drawn. To answer our question we want
the probability $X$ is either 0 or 2.

In R statistical software, here is how to print the PDF of the particular
hypergeometric distribution required.

```
x = 0:2;  pdf = dhyper(x, 3, 2, 2) # 3 Red, 2 Non-red, 2 drawn
cbind(x, pdf)
     x pdf
  ## 0 0.1
  ## 1 0.6
  ## 2 0.3
```

*Notes:* (1) For sampling with replacement, draws are independent and you could use the binomial distribution.
(2) It is difficult to make sense of unordered samples with replacement for
drawing balls from a bag. (But physicists have discovered that unordered sampling with replacement gives correct answers for some problems in sub-atomic physics.)

Comment: Thanks for you explicit answer. The question is exactly the same as the first 2 lines of my question, I just copy it directly. Besides,the answer of the question is $1-\frac{nP3}{n^3}$. Assume n = 5 and I tried to do it using the ordered method which is $1-\frac{nC3}{7C3}$, plug in n=5 , they don't have the same result.

Comment: where P is permutations and C is combinations

Comment: For an exact answer, I think you need to know how many balls there are of each of the three colors. Is that what you mean by $n$? For 3 colors and sampling with replacement, see the multinomial distribution.

Comment: Yes. In your Notes (2), why is it doesn't make sense to have unordered samples when we draw balls from a bag? (with replacement)

Comment: Partly because the process of 'draw and replace', 'draw and replace", etc. imposes an order. Try doing the example in my Answer with replacement and writing down a sample space of equally-likely outcomes that makes sense. See Comment of @Macavity. (For me, it is Monday morning before coffee; I have learned from experience I shouldn't do combinatorics in such circumstances.)

Comment: OK, thank you very much!!